# HTML Stylesheet changing bug

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I implemented a HTML stylesheet changing option on my website. However , there is a slight bug which I cannot seem to fix or figure out. When I click on a option to change the stylesheet it seems to bug out and it will not select it. If I click on a different option and then click back onto the same stylesheet it works.

Anyone know why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function setActiveStyle(styletitle) {
  var stylelist = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
  for (i = 0; i < stylelist.length; i++) {
    if (isOptionalStylesheet(stylelist[i])) {
      activateWhenMatching(stylelist[i], styletitle);
    }
  }
}

function isOptionalStylesheet(thislink) {
  return (thislink.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1) &&
    thislink.getAttribute("title")
}

function activateWhenMatching(thislink, styletitle) {
  if (thislink.getAttribute("title") == styletitle) {
    thislink.disabled = false;
  } else {
    thislink.disabled = true;
  }
}

function chooseStyleBySize() {
  var theWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (theWidth < 800) {
    theSheet = "smallsheet";
  } else if (theWidth < 900) {
    theSheet = "mediumsheet";
  } else {
    theSheet = "bigsheet";
  }
  setActiveStyle(theSheet);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen.css" title="bigsheet" />
  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alternativeCSS2.css" title="mediumsheet" />
  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alternativeCSS3.css" title="smallsheet" />
  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alternativeCSS4.css" title="specialsheet" />
</head>

<body onload="chooseStyleBySize()">
  <div id="layout">
    <div id="swapping">
      <p>
        <select onchange="setActiveStyle(this.value)">
                  <option value="bigsheet">For big pages</option>
                  <option value="mediumsheet">For medium-sized pages</option>
                  <option value="smallsheet">For small pages</option>
                  <option value="specialsheet">For special pages</option>
               </select>
```

Comment: You should try putting this into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: tried it but doesn't seem to be working, thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is working correct! There is no bug! I have tried with .css different background color like this

```
body {
    background: red;
}
```

Maybe your CSS files have some problems. You can give us your CSS files and then we will have all project for control.