# How can I validate the select tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For a school assignment I had to redesign a website, this is a part of my website where I created a form for the users. This is my first year and everything is new for me so don't be mad at me if I don't understand what you say :)!
[This is the design of the website and all the other input fields are allready validated, because it's a long code I didn't want to share it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq3h7.jpg)

My teacher told me that the more Javascript I use the more points I get for a higher grade. And he also said that all the form validations needs to be made in Javascript.

I allready made the validation of the other input fields, but with the HTML select tag/dropdown menu I do not succeed. I tried different codes and ways but no.. At this moment I don't have any code for the select tag, only what I've already made for the other inputfields..

This is the HTML code of the select tag/dropdown menu

```
<label for ="data">Kies een datum</label>
        <select name="datum">
        <option value="datum">15 april 2017</option>
        <option value="datum">18 april 2017</option>
        <option value="datum">21 april 2017</option>
        <option value="datum">26 april 2017</option>
```

What I want with this dropdown menu is an alert at the moment that no option is chosen...

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Well I tried a lot of things and I got so mad that I deleted it... Is it really necessary?

Comment: If we don't know what you tried, we can't tell you why it didn't work. Please always post the code you are working with  and the specific problem you are having. "Didn't work" doesn't really tell us much. You haven't really even told us what you are trying to do. "Validate" could mean many things.

Comment: Well it's my first time that I am posting something here so I didn't really know the rules. As I said I am doing this for hours, at a given moment I really got sick of it and deleted everything I tried..

Comment: ...And yet, you still won't tell us what you mean by "validate" or what it is you are trying to accomplish. Why do you need JavaScript to solve your issue? Why not use the pure HTML answer given below?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I assume they mean by validation that an option from the list must be selected, at least that is what is said below the code.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Could be, but since an answer was given that addresses that and given that the OP hasn't been specific about anything really, we need more info.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Look I have a dropdown menu, made in HTML with the select tag. The option value are different dates where the user can choose from. The user is required to choose a date, if they won't do this I want an alert who tells them that that field is required. Is it clear now?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes that's what I mean..

Comment: Can you help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746653/html-stylesheet-changing-bug/43746984#43746984

Comment: @BusraOgultay That is clear. And GetOffMyLawn provided you with the answer that doesn't require any JavaScript, but you indicated that you wanted a JavaScript answer and you didn't like that answer. Why?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am sorry I don't understand what you saying... And I also want to say this, I'm a first years student and everything is new for me. So sorry if I am not clear enough ;)

Comment: You were given a solution to your question that only requires you to add `required` into the `select` tag. No JavaScript is needed to solve your problem. Yet, you indicated that that answer was not suitable for you and you asked how to accomplish this in JavaScript. Why do you need JavaScript?

Comment: I need Javascript because there is a whole form and the validiation off that is also made in Javascript... I will post a picture of the website one moment

Comment: That makes no sense. You don't need any JavaScript for validating your `select`. We've told you this. You may need it for other elements of your form (and that's fine), but there is no law that says that all validation must be done in JavaScript. Is there some other requirement that you aren't telling us?

Comment: No there is no other requirement that I am not telling you.. As I said everything is new for me I don't know a lot about it. I thought that al the validations had to be created in Javascript.. 

There is no other requirement but my teacher said to me that he wants a form validation in Javascript. This assignment is my resignation so I am really afraid that I will fail and my teacher also said the more Javascript I use, the more points I get for a higher grade..  @ScottMarcus

Comment: *There is no other requirement but my teacher said to me that he wants a form validation in Javascript.* Well, that is a requirement that you hadn't told us!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `required` attribute to the `select`, then you need to have an empty option (with an empty value).

This will warn the user in supported browsers. You should still validate the code on the backend or unsupported browsers will still send the data.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="data">Kies een datum</label>
    <select id="data" name="datum" required>
        <option value="">Please Select a date...</option>
        <option value="datum">15 april 2017</option>
        <option value="datum">18 april 2017</option>
        <option value="datum">21 april 2017</option>
        <option value="datum">26 april 2017</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the result in Chrome

[image: Unselected]

Comment: @BusraOgultay You need to tell us what you are trying to do. The above answer has no JavaScript in it at all. It relies on the HTML `required` attribute to force the user to select something. But, since we don't know what you mean by "validate", we can't be more specific.

Comment: If you were going to use this technique, the first `option` should look like this: `<option value="">Please choose...</option>`, rather than a blank first `option`. Think about user accessibility and good UX.

Comment: Just add `id=data` to the `select` to make the `label` work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code block. The `for` attribute of the label tag should correspond to the `id` attribute of the select tag. The `value` attribute of each option should be unique and preferably machine readable.

```
<label for="datum">Kies een datum</label>
<select name="datum" id="datum">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="2017-04-15">15 april 2017</option>
  <option value="2017-04-18">18 april 2017</option>
  <option value="2017-04-21">21 april 2017</option>
  <option value="2017-04-26">26 april 2017</option>
</select>
```

Afterwards you can check that the field has a non-empty value.

jQuery:

```
if ($('select[name="datum"]').val()){
    // has a value so do something
} else {
    // is empty so do something else
}
```

Vanilla JS:

```
var datum = document.getElementById('datum');
var datumValue = datum.options[datum.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: The `for` attribute of a `label` corresponds to the `id` of the target element, not the `name`. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) Also, the `value` attribute can have any value at all as long as it makes sense to the form processor.

Comment: Amended the answer. Thanks

Comment: Hello thank you for your help! But the $ sign is JQuery right? My teacher rejected to use JQuery...

Comment: You used the jquery tag on the question!

Comment: @BusraOgultay  Ah ha! Now we have it. This is an assignment for school and the requirement to use JavaScript (although not needed to solve the problem) comes from the assignment. If you had just added that to your question in the beginning, we would have been able to help you much sooner.

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry... I found it difficult to express what the problem is haha...

Comment: @BusraOgultay In computing, there is a very old saying *"Garbage in...garbage out"* meaning that if your code is bad, you'll get a bad result. This is true of questions. if you ask a bad (incomplete) question, you will get bad answers. ;)

Comment: Well mister @ScottMarcus I edited my question I hope that it is good and clear now ;)

Answer (score -1):

When a user submits a form, the `form` element's `submit` event is triggered. This is the event where you can do all your validation (assuming that you are OK with waiting until the user submits to inform them that there are validation errors).

One other note. The `label` element must point to the `id` of the element it relates to using the `for` attribute. Your `label` points to `data`, yet your `select` doesn't have an `id` at all.

Here is the working HTML and JavaScript:

```js
// First, get a reference to the form. There are many ways to do that
// but, in the HTML, I've given the form an id and that is a simple
// way to find it in JavaScript
var frm = document.getElementById("frmTest");

// We'll also need a reference to any other HTML elements you want to work with
var sel = document.getElementById("data");

// Now, set up the form to call a function when its submit event is triggered
frm.addEventListener("submit", validate);

// Here's the function that will be executed when the submit event occurs
// It will automaticaly be passed an argument that represents the submit
// event itsef (here, we're receiving it as "evt").
function validate(evt){

  // Perform any validations you desire
  
  // Check to see if the user has selected anything from the drop down
  if(sel.value === ""){
    // The select has no value, so the first option must still be chosen
    
    evt.preventDefault();  // cancel the submit event
    evt.stopPropagation(); // stop the event from bubbling to other elements
    
    alert("You haven't chosen anything from the list!");
  }
  
  // The select has a value. Let the event proceed as normal.


}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="" id="frmTest">
 
   <!-- The "for" attribute must point to the "id" of another element -->
  <label for ="data">Kies een datum</label>
  
  <select name="datum" id="data">
    <!-- Notice that the first option has an empty string as its value?
         That's what will make the first option not a valid choice.      -->
    <option value="">...Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="datum">15 april 2017</option>
    <option value="datum">18 april 2017</option>
    <option value="datum">21 april 2017</option>
    <option value="datum">26 april 2017</option> 
  </select>
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    
</form>
```

Comment: <form name="meeloopdag" class="meelopen" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="send">

I allready have this before the select tag, can I add the form action etc in this code?

Comment: You would just alter the `form` tag shown in my answer to match your `name`, `class`, `method` and `action` values. The `onsubmit` should come out and not be used at all (this is an old technique that is not recommended for many reasons). I am performing the `onsubmit` operation in the JavaScript section with the `frm.addEventListener(...)` line. But do leave the `id` in the `form` tag so that it is easily accessible from JavaScript.

Comment: I did what you said but it doesn't work and my other alert I had before for the other input fields is also gone..

Comment: @BusraOgultay This code is correct as you can see by running it. If you've taken this code and injected with your own, the problem must be with your other code. This is the correct way to validate a required field via JavaScript. This is what you asked for.

Comment: I know what I asked for. Unfortunately it doesn't work together with my other code. Thanks anyway ;).

Comment: @BusraOgultay If you don't/won't show us that code, there is literally no way we can help you.

Comment: I can show it and I also want to show it, but I don't want to take too much time from you.. @Scott Marcus

Comment: And it's mostly in Dutch.. If you say that's okey than I will share it with you

Comment: The JavaScript won't be in Dutch. I'm just saying that there's no possible way to help you if you won't show us the code you are dealing with.

Comment: SO never ceases to amaze me. A down vote for the correct answer with explanation and working code example. Nice!